# AG Grid Pivot Aggregation as Columns

Tags: angular, typescript, grid, ag-grid

We are using the AG Grid in our application.

We've the ui component as follows

```
  public rowData = [
{ order: 1, amount: 100, model: "A"},
{ order: 2, amount: 200, model: "A"},
{ order: 3, amount: 100, model: "A"},
{ order: 4, amount: 200, model: "A"},
{ order: 5, amount: 100, model: "B"},
{ order: 6, amount: 200, model: "B"},
{ order: 7, amount: 100, model: "B"},
{ order: 8, amount: 100, model: "C"},
{ order: 9, amount: 100, model: "C"},
{ order: 10, amount: 200, model: "D"},
  ];

  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
{ field: 'model', pivot: true },
{ field: 'order', aggFunc: 'count' },
{ field: 'amount', aggFunc: 'sum' }
  ];

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [pivotMode]="true"
  [rowData]="rowData"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

By using this, we would like to display following grid to the user
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5EIG.png)

I've tried having the Pivot on the Model. and we are able to generate the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CESa.png)

i'm also not sure on how to transpose. Can we get somehelp on resolving this

Plnkr -
https://plnkr.co/edit/1bSu5mEhpUp9YIfw?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can achive desired result by using [header groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-groups/) in ag-grid. just define your columns definition like this.

```
columnDefs: (ColDef | ColGroupDef)[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'A',
      headerClass: 'ag-right-aligned-header',
      children: [
        {
          headerName: 'COUNT',
          field: 'a_count',
          width: 150,
          cellClass: 'cellCenter'
        },
        {
          headerName: 'SUM',
          field: 'a_sum',
          width: 90,
          minWidth: 75,
          maxWidth: 100,
          cellClass: 'cellCenter'
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      headerName: 'B',
      children: [
        {
          headerName: 'COUNT',
          field: 'b_count',
          width: 150,
        },
        {
          headerName: 'SUM',
          field: 'b_sum',
          width: 90,
          minWidth: 75,
          maxWidth: 100,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

then refactor your data like this.

```
rowData = [
    // { section: 'sub-section', a: 'Count', c: 'Sum' },
    { a_count: 230, a_sum: 160, b_count: 233, b_sum: 330 },
    { a_count: 250, a_sum: 460, b_count: 213, b_sum: 690 },
    { a_count: 280, a_sum: 200, b_count: 633, b_sum: 560 },
    { a_count: 220, a_sum: 760, b_count: 453, b_sum: 990 },
  ];
```

I have created a [stckblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-udyzmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example for you. just add vertical column borders.
please  upvote/accept answer if it helps.